# Complex Analysis text for beginners.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a graduate student of Mathematics.I am planning to study complex analysis.I am a beginner,so I want a book to help me understand each idea.I have referred to J B Conway-Complex analysis book but it is not good for beginners like me.I am mainly interested in studying contour integration and Cauchy's theorem and analytic functions.Can somebody help me find a suitable book?

Comment: People really like " Visual Complex analysis - Tristan Needham ".

Comment: The book is definitely not one suitable for math majors, it's more like a book for developing an interest in the subject

Comment: @Buraian I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties of holomorphic functions comes the fact that the function has a derivative, like the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Other properties such the discreteness of roots or the maximum modulus principle, comes from the fact that the function is analytic. I think Serge Lang's Complex Analysis does a good job in splitting analyticity   and holomorphism up and making sure we know what comes from what before telling us that all holomorphic functions are analytic. Tao's notes for 246A is also a very good place to start if you put in the time to solve all the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

I thought "Foundations of Complex Analysis" by 'S.Ponnusamy' is a very well written book for beginners. It contains dozen of exercises for better understanding each concepts and one more good book for understanding/imagining complex analysis is "Visual Complex analysis" by 'Tristan Needham'.