# Good books to learn Complex Analysis and Contour Integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, book-recommendation, advice

I have completely finished some of calculus, such as Limits, Derivatives, Sequence and series, Indefinite and Definite Integration and many more. And have solved humongous amount questions on these topics. I am also good with basics. So to expand my knowledge more, I wanna self study Complex analysis and Contour Integration as I did for previous topics. Can you please suggest some good books for them? Starting from stratch so that it's easy for me to self study? It don't have to be one book, can be series of books too. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: Mathematics for physics and physicists - Walter Appel is fairly good. It is used by physicists, but the content is slightly watered down, which makes it a good introduction since it goes straight to the point. This book is still good enough for a math undergraduate. A physics background is not required to understand the part about complex analysis and contour integration. If you are starting from scratch, this is probably a decent suggestion. Hardcore math references will be tough on you I think

Comment: Hillary Priestley's book on complex analysis is very friendly ( at university level anyway).

Comment: I am personally happy with "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory", Bruce Palka, especially, since MathSE is a fail-safe for any of the book's exercises that I can't solve.

Comment: "Complex Analysis", Eberhard Freitag, Rolf Busam. It is a really good introduction. From differential calculus in the complex plane to elliptic functions, elliptic modular forms and analytic number theory. There are solutions to the exercises.

Comment: The "Introduction to Complex Analysis" book here is good: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/complex-analysis-course/. It assumes real analysis background. Background on real analysis is given there in the "Introduction to Analysis in One Variable" book.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217168/complex-analysis-text-for-beginners

Comment: It depends on whether you only want to *use* complex analysis for computations (as physicists or engineers do) or you want to do some proofs (as mathematicians do). In the latter case, I think you need to deepen your knowledge in classical analysis first before dappling in complex analysis. E.g. you need to learn some point set topology and learn what is uniform convergence of sequences or series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Complex Analysis (Princeton Lectures in Analysis, Volume II)](https://www.fing.edu.uy/%7Ecerminar/Complex_Analysis.pdf) written by Elias M. Stein (Ph.D advisor of the famous Professor Terrence Tao) and Rami Shakarchi. This is the second analysis book in the serious of books and the authors aim to sacrifice the depth of presented topics in exchange for the demonstration of various connections of the materials to other branch of mathematics, which in my mind will help you to hunt for next interested topics in your mind along the journey.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch and completely rigorous (way more rigorous than a few suggestions on this page, no hand-waving whatsoever) is "Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable" by Markushevich. If you have the freedom to invest a good time in it, it is the book to go.

Answer (score 0):

I too am starting to learn contour integration and some things what I have found useful so far I detail for you.

At this [site](https://residuetheorem.com/2015/01/08/the-art-of-using-the-residue-theorem-in-evaluating-definite-integrals/) down in the comments some book suggestions can be found.

At the same site is many interesting examples for contour integration and the author might respond if something is not clear. In any case it's free.

If it's learning with math software then, though old, William T. Shaw - Complex Analysis with MATHEMATICA is quite good.

Also Lars Ahlfors - Complex Analysis has some useful examples.

In any case borrow them before buying - many a time what works for one person might not for another.